# Get an ordered vector of objects from a binary tree class template

Tags: c++, templates, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I want to have a vector list inside a binary tree so that when `main` asks for a ordered list I can get the binary tree class to use `inorder` to add each elemType object in the correct order into the orderedList vector. Then this list will be returned or made public and accessed so that I can get the orderedList out of the binary tree.

I can not use `cout` because the data type is more complex and needs to be fully returned inside the vector.

I made some comments in the code to better illustrate my problem:

`BinaryTree.h`

```
// I am using this tree mainly with a data class that holds different data
// types (int, string, ect...)

// This is my node in the binary tree
template <class elemType>
struct nodeType
{
    elemType info; // create the variable to hold the data
    nodeType<elemType> *lLink;
    nodeType<elemType> *rLink;
};

template <class elemType>
class BinaryTree
{
    public:

    // I want to use inorder to put a ordered list of the tree contents
    // into the orderedList
    vector<elemType> orderedList;

    void inorder (nodeType<elemType> *p) const;

};

// definitions:

template <class elemType>
void BinaryTree<elemType>::inorder(nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{
    // Instead of using cout I want to push_back the elemType object
    // into the orderedList vector (because I want to return the vector
    // to main so I can list the details inside the elemType object
    if (p != NULL)
    {
            // the big issue is right here, how to push_back to the orderedvector
            // and get the elemType inside the node into the vector?
            inorder (p -> lLink);
            cout << p -> info << " ";// I can't use cout!
            inorder (p -> rLink);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I tried using `orderedList.push_back(p -> info);`

instead of `cout` and I got this error:

`error C2663: 'std::vector<_Ty>::push_back' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`void inorder (nodeType<elemType> *p) const;` is a const member function. You cannot (logical) modify the `BinaryTree` instance in this function. `inorder` should just return a vector like this:

```
template <class elemType>
class BinaryTree
{
public:
  vector<elemType> inorder (nodeType<elemType> *p) const {
    vector<elemType> v;
    add_inorder(v, p);
    return v;
  }

private:
  void add_inorder(vector<elemType>& v, nodeType<elemType>* p)
  {
    if (p != NULL){
        add_inorder(p -> lLink);
        v.push_back(p);
        add_inorder(p -> rLink);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: When I call the inorder function from main I am getting a error that inorder takes more than zero arguments. But I can't add arguments. see: `vector<StockData> tmp; tmp = JoesBinaryTree.inorder();`

Comment: @Joseph You are the author of this function, you should know what to pass or not to pass to the function. The `inorder` function from your original post took an argumetn of type `nodeType<elemType>*`. If this pointer should point to an internal node (the first node??) remove the argument and pass in to `add_inorder` from `inorder`